# Did Cretan Greek have [s] as an allophone of /ts/ after a nasal?

Tags: phonology, phonetics, greek

Wikipedia cites Hinge (2001) as reporting the claim that Cretan Greek had [s] as an allophone of /ts/ after a nasal. I’m not a German speaker so I can’t verify this.

The relevant section from the Wikipedia page for [Zeta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeta#Arguments_for_%5Bzd%5D) is quoted below (as viewed on the 30th of January 2024)

> 6. ν disappears before ζ like before σ(σ), στ: e.g. *πλάνζω > πλᾰ́ζω, *σύνζυγος > σύζυγος, *συνστέλλω > σῠστέλλω. Contra: ν may have disappeared before /dz/ if one accepts that it had the allophone [z] in that position like /ts/ had the allophone [s]: cf. Cretan ἴαττα ~ ἀποδίδονσα (Hinge).

Citing: Hinge, George. “Die Aussprache des griechischen Zeta”, in Die Sprache Alkmans: Textgeschichte und Sprachgeschichte. PhD dissertation. Aarhus: Aarhus University Press, 2001, pp. 212–234 = [[1]](http://alkman.georgehinge.com/zeta.html)

I’m really looking for an English translation of Hinge 2001 so I can verify that it does indeed claim this fact.

Comment: Do you mean the dialect of Ancient Greek, or the dialect of Modern Greek, or the non-Indo-European language that Greek displaced?

Comment: it seems unlikely that a dialect of Greek (or from what we can guess based on loans into Greek and the structure of the later Linear B alphabet, the Minoan or Eteocretan languages) had a /ts/ phoneme. Have you got the brackets and allophony relation the right way round? Having [ts] as an allophone of /s/ after a nasal is much more plausible. It would probably also help if you could quote the specific claim given on wikipedia (as well as a link, together with the date you accessed it)

Comment: Hinge (2001) is a dissertation on the language of the Spartan poet Alcman (7th century BC), who wrote in the Doric (Laconian) dialect of Sparta, so I wonder how it is connected with Crete. You definitely need to add more details.

Comment: @Draconis the Ancient Greek one before the classical period

Comment: @QuinaliSolaji thank you for the additional information. Nonetheless, the claim you are presenting as from wikipedia seems extremely dubious. Can you please give us a link to the original article (and location within the article) as to me it seems that you may have misinterpreted the claim being made

Comment: @Tristan in https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeta there is a category called “Uses” under it are a series of arguments for zeta being /zd/ or /dz/. In argument 6 of /zd/ there is a Contra that makes this claim

Comment: thank you. I have edited this in to the question

Comment: My German is far from fluent, but searching through the linked article for `/ts/` and then running those paragraphs through google translate (the fact this is generally more useful that relying on my own translation, shows how far I am from fluent, hence why this is not an answer), it appears that the /ts/ phoneme being discussed is the Proto-Greek /ts/ < first palatalisation of *ty or *tʰy, claiming the earlier [ts] sound of this phoneme persisted late in Cretan, as it was spelt <ζ> in the archaic period and later with <ττ> or <θθ>

Comment: He then cites Cretan -ονσα for Attic -ουσα < Proto-Greek *ontsa < PIE *-ontih2 (the feminine nominative singular of the thematic active present participle) as evidence of a [s] allophone of /ts/ in Cretan. I'm not confident enough in the google translation to say for sure, but he might also be claiming such an allophone in Proto-Greek more generally